# Cannot Set Background Element to Fixed Position

Tags: html, css, mobile

I am having trouble setting my background image to where it is centered on the screen as you scroll down on a mobile device.

Currently, my website's background when scrolling on my desktop is as how I want it to be. The problem is on mobile devices and for some reason when using dev tools to view the site on mobile resolutions it works great but when it comes to real practice, it does not work.

Can anyone please help me figure this out?

My current code is:

```
    body.custom-background, #custom-background-css {

    background-position: center center !important;
    min-height: 100%;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

My website is: test.ebdesigns.us 
(wordpress platform)

Also, when viewing source-code something is producing this and do not know. This might be affecting it.

```
<style type="text/css" id="custom-background-css">
body.custom-background { background-image: url('http://www.test.ebdesigns.us/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/NewColumbis51Logorev101.jpg'); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: top center; background-attachment: fixed; }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually some plugin is sending this "body.custom-background" your CSS, but this is not the case

Change your code to say > background-position : "**top center**", instead of "*center center*". That will do

**If you want to preserve the center center you have to provide a height to your main container(body)

```
body.custom-background, #custom-background-css {    
    background-position: center center !important;
    min-height: 100%;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    height:100vh;
}
```

Cheers. joy

Comment: Nope, it just moves the image to the top on my mobile device, just tried it.

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "Actually some plugin is sending this "body.custom-background" your CSS, but this is not the case"? I have a plugin interfering?

Comment: Actually from your original post:"Also, when viewing source-code something is producing this and do not know. This might be affecting it." but that shouldn't be a problem

Comment: So any ideas why I cannot have the image set in the background of the phone fixed while scrolling?

Comment: adding height: 100vh; to your existing css didn't work??

Comment: I will attach some screens it actually worked for me.

Comment: Here the screen grabs from my system with [chromeinspect](https://c7f59743e2a1e1c0bb945b1aad55bef2824d4784.googledrive.com/host/0B9KwHu7kahaxfnRuVEdUZEgtWl8wbzRtdWlJeGNkaHBlOEhDUHAySERfUlRHVkpPb0pGYkk/chromeinspect.jpg) and from my [chrome mobile](https://c7f59743e2a1e1c0bb945b1aad55bef2824d4784.googledrive.com/host/0B9KwHu7kahaxfnRuVEdUZEgtWl8wbzRtdWlJeGNkaHBlOEhDUHAySERfUlRHVkpPb0pGYkk/chromemobile.jpg)

Please check the article on [chrome inspect](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging)

Hope I have answered it correctly !

Comment: If you think that the fix worked could you accept and upvote please

Comment: No, it didn't work and I found out that mobile browsers do not support background-attachment: fixed; :(

Comment: you checked my mobile screenshot I used chrome on Samsung note edge and HTC one M8 both worked. strange not working at your end !! Sorry ran out of options :(

Comment: Yeah, it works where you can see the image in the background but it does not stay fixed when you scroll :(

Comment: Also, if you can help me give the background img an opacity? If so then i'll upvote you.

Comment: Did you try with a different image?? just luck maybe :( try a small image 300x300

Comment: Nvm, I created another image in photoshop and I switch the image using jQuery.